# Cannot shutdown factory in Play + Hibernate

Tags: scala, hibernate, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using Hibernate in Play for Scala, and whenever I touch the code and Play restarts, I get the following error:

> Exception: Failure in readMany: admin.manage.BankHib cannot be
>   cast to admin.manage.BankHib

Since the error says that the class cannot be cast to itself, I believe the problem is that the class loaders are different.

This is how I start and close the Hibernate sessions factory:

```
object HibernateUtil {

   val sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory

   def buildSessionFactory = {
      try {
            new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory
      } 
      catch {case ex:Throwable => 
                        println("SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
      }
  }

  def shutdown  {
    sessionFactory.close
  }
}
```

And the following singleton is run when Play restarts:

```
@Singleton
class HibernateService @Inject()(lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) {

      lifecycle.addStopHook { () =>
        Future.successful{
          println("Hibernate sessions shutdown")
          HibernateUtil.shutdown
        }
      } 
}
```

Even though the factory is closed, I still get the cast error. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: I doubt shutdowning factory has effect on class loaders